# Confuse What should be my Xpath Expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xpath

My categories.xml file is given below

```
<categories>
  <root name="Cars -Vehicles" id="CV"></root>
  <root name="Personals" id="PER"></root>
  <root name="Real Estate" id="RE"></root>
  <root name="Property For Rent" id="PFR"></root>
  <root name="Community" id="COM"></root>
</categories>
```

and My attibutes.xml file is given below

```
<attributes>

  <attribute value="ethnicity=ethnicity_african_american" name ="American Indian" categoryid="PER"/>
  <attribute value="ethnicity=ethnicity_asian_pacific_islander" name ="Asian - Pacific Islander" categoryid="PER"/>
  <attribute value="ethnicity=ethnicity_caucasian" name ="Caucasian" categoryid="PER"/>


  <attribute value="amenities=amenities_ac" name ="AC" categoryid="RE, PFR"/>
  <attribute value="amenities=amenities_alarm" name ="Alarm" categoryid="RE, PFR"/>

</attributes>
```

I bound my `attributeDropdown` on selection of `categoriesDropDown`. Code is given below

```
 protected void ddCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            XmlDataSource xd = new XmlDataSource();
            xd.DataFile = Server.MapPath("Xmls") + "\\attributes.xml";
            xd.XPath = "/attributes/attribute[@categoryid='" + 
                        categoriesDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString() + "']";

            attributeDropdown.DataSource = xd;
            attributeDropdown.DataTextField = "name";
            attributeDropdown.DataValueField = "value";

            attributeDropdown.DataBind();

         // categoriesDropDown.DataTextField = "name";
         // categoriesDropDown.DataValueField = "id";

 }
```

Now the problem is two attributes named **AC** and **Alarm** are in two categories ***Real Estate*** and ***Property For Rent***. How can I bind these attributes on selection of these categories ?

**Insort what should be my Xpath Expression if attributes are in multiple categories?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it isn't good solution, but you can use `contains` function, e.g.:

```
/attributes/attribute[contains(@categoryid, 'category')]
```

According to your code:

```
xd.XPath = string.Format("/attributes/attribute[contains(@categoryid, '{0}')]",
    categoriesDropDown.SelectedValue);
```